# Cannot access file in current working directory - 'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory'

Tags: python, windows

I have seen multiple other questions regarding this but none that answer my question. I am getting the error 
`'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'` even though my current working directory matches that of the location of the file.

I have tried hardcoding the file location using `python ex15.py C:\Users\Matt\py\sample.txt`however i get `'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Matt\\py\\sample.txt'`

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print(f"Here's your filename {filename}:")

print(txt.read())

print("Type the filename again")

file_again = input("> ")
variable
text_again = open(file_again)

print(txt_again.read())
```

Current working directory is C:\Users\Matt\py. When I try to hardcode it gives two backslashes (\) which I assume is causing an issue, but I would like to be able to do it without hardcoding anyway.

Thanks.

Comment: What evidence do you have that that file actually exists?

Comment: My crystal ball says: Try `python ex15.py C:\Users\Matt\py\sample.txt.txt`. Does that work?

Comment: A double backlash represents a single backlash. This is because backslashes are used to create special escape characters like `\n` for newline, so intuitively you’d need to escape the backslash with another one. If you want to avoid this, use raw strings prefixed with an `r` like: `r'C:\Users\Matt'`

Comment: melpomene that worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your file is not actually called `sample.txt`. Its real name is `sample.txt.txt`. It just happens to look like `sample.txt` in the GUI because you're using Windows and you've told Windows Explorer to hide extensions in file names.

See also:

- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/activedirectoryua/2013/05/22/how-to-see-those-file-extensions-in-windows/
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/how-to-display-file-extensions-in-w-10/226d323d-978a-47de-bd1d-8780643897e3